# DRF - Testing, error while hitting sinlgle data from id

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework, testcase

**Urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('zone', views.ZoneViewSet, basename='zone')

app_name = 'address'
API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Test.py**

```
RECIPES_URL = reverse('address:zone-list')

def details_url(id):
    print(RECIPES_URL,id)
    return reverse(RECIPES_URL.strip(),args=[id])

print -> /api/address/zone/ 1

def test_zone_details(self):
   task = sample_payload()
   url = details_url(task.id)
   res = self.client.get(url)
   self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

ERROR: test_zone_details (address.tests.ZoneApiTestCase)

```
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
```

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/api/address/zone/' not found. '/api/address/zone/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 0):

Detail url is simply `reverse("zone-detail", kwargs={"pk": task.id})`, with "zone" your basename and "pk" your url param name.
The `-detail` is documentated here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/.
I admit it is not always easy to find what you're looking for in DRF doc.

Comment: I want to send an id in params and get that item in response but I got an error if you have good knowledge then help me out. I am new to python.

Comment: i have follow this link - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-django-test-driven-development-of-web-api-using-drf-docker/?ref=rp

Comment: I updated my answer with the way to include the id

Comment: i have already tried this but does not work for me

Comment: The error is still the same ?